# Does there exist an entire function $f$ such that if $z=x+iy$, $Re(f(z))=e^x$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist an entire function such that if $z=x+iy$, $Re(f(z))=e^x$.

An entire function is completely determined by its values on any line segment and the value of $f(z)$ on the real axis is $e^x$ so clearly the function must be $f(z)=e^z$. But that does not match up with the data $Re(f(z))=e^x$. Is this correct? Is there another more elegant method to do this?

Comment: Your title is very from the the actual question in the body though. Please edit to reflect what you actually want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

The real and imaginary part of a holomorphic function is harmonic, so there can be no such $f$.

Comment: could you explain in further detail?

Comment: It's a standard result which almost surely is in your textbook (and follows directly from Cauchy-Riemann's equations) that if $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic (i.e. $u''_{xx} + u''_{yy} = 0$ and similarly for $v$). In your case $u = e^x$, and $u''_{xx} + u''_{yy} = e^x \neq 0$.